# How to change network interface used by Android?

Tags: adb, wi-fi, networking

When I boot up my Android Device and go to WiFi settings, the status of WiFi remains "Turning Wi-Fi on" forever. I looked it up in logcat logs, and below is the error that I see.

```
E/wpa_supplicant( 1713): nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
E/wpa_supplicant( 1713): wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
E/wpa_supplicant( 1713): Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
```

Below is some useful information.

```
root@android:/ # netcfg
netcfg    
lo       UP     127.0.0.1/8   0x00000049 00:00:00:00:00:00
gannet0  DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00001082 1e:e9:6e:bf:45:f7
dummy0   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000082 ba:ad:f6:ae:6a:09
rmnet0   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet1   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet2   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet3   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet4   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet5   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet6   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000000 00:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet7   DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000001 00:00:00:00:00:00
sit0     DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00
ip6tnl0  DOWN     0.0.0.0/0   0x00000080 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Contents of `/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=wlan0
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1
```

**Question**: How can I enable Android to use some other interface other than `wlan0`?

Things tried:

1. I tried to edit `ctrl_interface` parameter in `/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` using `adb pull` and `adb push` to other interfaces shown by `netcfg`, but Android still tries to use `wlan0`.
2. I also tried to start `wpa_supplicant` daemon using the below command.

   ```
   /system/bin/wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -idummy0 -c/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```

   but this gives an error.

   ```
   E/wpa_supplicant( 5390): dummy0: Failed to initialize driver interface
   ```

Comment: You also need to change the init.{hardware}.rc file with correct socket name (wpa_dummy0)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `dummy` is a WiFi interface? The typical WiFi interface's name is `wlan0`.

If you're 100% sure it is the right WiFi interface, you might also need to change the `wlan0` inside the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

If that still fails, run the `wpa_supplicant` command under `strace` and try to get more info from there.

Answer (score 0):

Run in an ADB shell:

```
wpa_cli
```

It will open a new type of shell in which:

- Command `help` will give you all possible commands.
- Command `interface` will show you all your activated interfaces.
- Command `interface_add` will add a new interface to use, with following parameters

  ```
  interface_add <ifname> <confname> <driver> <ctrl_interface> <driver_param> <bridge_name>
  ```

  `ifname` being the single optional parameter.